# Proper Use Of Ternary Operator

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, echo

I'm trying to add 'NEW' to unread messages in the inbox. I don't think I can use an if statement within an echo and I have tried and failed to understand the proper use of ternary operators. I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

If read_yet = 'no' I want to add this code as another echo statement:

```
echo '<td>NEW</td>' ;
```

Here is my current code for the inbox.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from messages 
WHERE deleted = 'no' AND to_user = '" . $_GET['username'] . "'
ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="profile.php?username=' ;
echo $row['from_user']  ;
echo '">';
echo '<img id="usersimage" src="images/profileimg/thumbnail_'.$row['from_user'];
echo '.jpg"</a></td>' ;
echo '<td><a href="users.php?username=' ;
echo $row['from_user']  ;
echo '">';
echo $row['from_user'];
echo "</a></td><td><a href='messageid.php?id=".$row['id']."'><font color='#b2ccdb'>" .$row['subject'] ;
echo '</a></font></td>';
echo '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: For me, I tend to use ternary operators in assignment, for example: `$myValueSet = isset($_POST['myValue']) ? 'YES' : 'NO'`. The first part is the expression. If it is true, it returns the second part, if false it returns the third part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding another column, I would not suggest using the ternary operator and instead simply using `if`:

```
if ($row['read_yet' == 'no') {
    echo '<td>NEW</td>';
}
```

However, if you always output this column and need to change the display, you could use the ternary operator.

```
echo '<td>' . ($row['read_yet' == 'no' ? 'NEW' : 'READ') . '</td>';
```

**Note:** The ternary can create line noise. As such, I prefer a temporary variable, helper function, or traditional `if`.

Comment: Amazing! Having a New & Read column was the right choice. Thank you so much! Learning this option now will help me a lot in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A ternary like this:

```
$foo = ($bar) ? 'true result' : 'false result';
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
if ($bar) {
   $foo = 'true result';
} else { 
   $foo = 'false result';
}
```

Comment: + for the general education.